# store images MeteorCamera.getPicture in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, meteor, camera

I am storing the images clicked via camera in a normal mongo collection. My whole db size is around 10MB and it works fine now. Following is the code for storing images :

```
MeteorCamera.getPicture(cameraOptions, function (error, data) {
      if(!error){

        var userGroup = UserDetails.findOne({userId : Meteor.userId()}).userGroup;
        DoubtThread.insert({
                    createdBy : Meteor.userId(),
                    createdAt : new Date(),
                    questionName : quesName,
                    userGroup : userGroup,
                    channelName : cname,                                                    
                    questionImage : data,
                    noOfLikes : 0,
                    noOfDislikes : 0,
                    noOfViews : 1
                });
```

Is it a good practice to follow? I searched and learnt theres a cfs gridCfs package to store images but I am not sure if that can be implemented with same ease as this is done.

PS: This is my first question so apologies for asking a very basic one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method will only pose a problem if the image size becomes too large (around 8MB maybe). Or if the number of images in your db becomes too many (I would say less than 100 should do fine).
If the image size is more than 16MB, mongo wont let you store the image in the db. And if the noOf images is too many, it might take more time to loas and hence frustrating the user!

Comment: So it seems that using this method wont be a problem in my case as neither of the conditions you mentioned are violated.

Comment: still you should read about the cfs package as its better to use : https://atmospherejs.com/cfs/gridfs

Comment: Thanks. Is it better to use amazon s3 or cfs?

Comment: hmm. Amazon s3 is better to use but difficult to understand and implement (my view)

Comment: could someone please share a tutorial or a link to understand cfs better as : atmospherejs.com/cfs/gridfs this link doesn't explain very well. I just need to know the syntax of declaring the db, synatx for storing files in it and retrieving from it